# many to many relationship

Tags: linq, many-to-many

I am trying to write a linq to get data from many to many tables.

Here are the tables

Products (ID,Name,Description)

Products_Items (ID,ProductID,Description)

ProductsNeeds (ID,Name)

ProductsItems_Needs (ItemID,NeedsID)

This is the t-sql query

```
select gPro.Name,gProItems.ShortDescription,gProItems.Description,gNeeds.Name
from Products gPro
join Products_Items gProItems on gPro.ID = gProItems.ProductID
join ProductsItems_Needs gProNeeds on gProNeeds.ItemID = gProItems.ID
join ProductsNeeds gNeeds on gNeeds.ID = gProNeeds.NeedsID
where gProItems.ID = 1
```

this is the linq

```
 var q = from p in objM.Products
         join gpItems in objM.Products_Items on p.ID equals gpItems.ProductID
         from needs in gpItems.ProductsNeeds
         where gpItems.ID == 1
         select p;
```

This query returns (Products) and it has the Produts_Items but it has not the ProductsNeeds.

What modifications should I do in order each Products_items to have the ProductsNeeds?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution.

The change was that instead of returning Products it returns Product_Items.

```
var q = from pItems in objM.Products_Items
join p in objM.Products on pItems.ID equals p.ID into joinedProducts
    from p in joinedProducts.DefaultIfEmpty()
from needs in pItems.ProductsNeeds
where pItems.ID == 1
select pItems;
```